# Laravel Database Query Builder error with table name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm making a "simple" api for laravel. This api has to handle with filters, pagination and sorting the result. To make this I use laravel query builder. The problem is that it's making a select without a table name, for example:

```
select * order by `id` asc
```

My code:

```
public function index()
{
    $request = request();

    $query = DB::table('customers')->newQuery();

    // Orden
    if (request()->has('sort')) {

        // Multiorden
        $sorts = explode(',', request()->sort);
        foreach ($sorts as $sort) {
            list($sortCol, $sortDir) = explode('|', $sort);
            $query = $query->orderBy($sortCol, $sortDir);
        }
    } else {
        $query = $query->orderBy('id', 'asc');
    }

    //Filtros
    if ($request->exists('filter')) {
        $query->where(function($q) use($request) {
            $value = "%{$request->filter}%";
            $q->where('name', 'like', $value)
            ->orWhere('address', 'like', $value);
        });
    }

    $perPage = request()->has('per_page') ? (int) request()->per_page : null;
    $pagination = $query->get()->paginate($perPage);
    $pagination->appends([
        'sort' => request()->sort,
        'filter' => request()->filter,
        'per_page' => request()->per_page
    ]);

    return response()->json(
        $pagination
    );
}
```

Error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1096 No tables used (SQL: select * order by `id` asc) in file
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\iService\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
>   on line 664

**UPDATE**:

```
return DB::table('customers')->get();
```

If i use this, the api works fine, I have more apis working. The problem is that I need Query Builder to handle filters, sort, etc...

[image]

Comment: are your database credentials correct? may I see a screenshot of it?

Comment: based on your error message, it seems your Query Builder was not able to find the table "customers" that's why you can't find the "id" column: **(SQL: select * order by id asc) in file**

Comment: @Noctis17 for me it's seems that I'm making a mistake on query builder, becaise with ->get() instead of ->newQuery() i get all the data back. If i have permissions error the other function will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way I instance a new query.

```
$query = DB::table('customers')->newQuery();
```

Correct:

```
$query = Model::query();
```

For my example:

```
$query = Customer::query();
```